# How to use Simple Dialog in Webform Module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

i want use Simple Dialog module and Webform module in Drupal 7.
I want open a webform popup or modal view. Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For webform with id = 2.

```
            <a class="simple-dialog"
               href="/node/2"
               name="webform-client-form-2"
               rel="width:900;resizable:false;position:[center,60]"
               title="My Dialog Title">Link name</a>
```